# How to query Enum using Prisma?

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

The goal is simple, I want to query enum field in the where clause. Example

prisma version is: `"prisma": "3.11.0"`

schema.prisma

```
model Todo {
  id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
  title String
  content String
  status TodoStatus @default(IN_PROGRESS)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

enum TodoStatus {
  IN_PROGRESS 
  DONE
}
```

api call

```
app.get('/todos', (req, res){
   const { status } = req.query
   const todos = await prisma.todo.findMany({
      where: { status: status },
      orderBy: {
        id: "asc",
      },
    });

    res.json(todos);
})
```

Frontend I use Next.js and it is a select option

example

```
            <select
              id="todo"
              name="todo"
              onChange={(e) => setSelectedStatus(e.target.value as Status)}
            >
              {[Status.IN_PROGRESS, Status.DONE].map((status: Status) => {
                return (
                  <option value={status}>{todoStatusToString[status]}</option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
```

The enum value from Next.js

```
export enum Status {
  IN_PROGRESS = "IN_PROGRESS",
  DONE = "DONE",
  ALL = "ALL",
}

export const todoStatusToString = {
  [Status.IN_PROGRESS]: "In progress",
  [Status.DONE]: "Done",
  [Status.ALL]: "All",
};
```

the `req.query` will be sent from clientside in this format

```
localhost:3000/todos?status=DONE

{ status: "DONE" }
```

or
localhost:3000/todos?status=IN_PROGRESS

```
{ status: "IN_PROGRESS" }
```

I know that Prisma is built-in to be typesafe. So my assumption is because the data that we get from the frontend is a string type while the enum on Prisma is looking for either `IN_PROGRESS` or `DONE` specifically if we send "DECLINED" to status where clause it will spit the same error.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Passing `DONE` or `IN_PROGRESS` as string should work. I just tried it out and it worked for me. What version of Prisma and Database are you using?
I tried it and it worked in PostgreSQL and prisma client verison of `3.7.0`

Comment: `"@prisma/client": "3.10.0"` this is my prisma version.

Comment: and im using postgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to cast the type.
You can do it like this

```js
where: { status: status as unknown as TodoStatus}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case the enums are called `Role` in the schema rather than `TodoStatus`.
My error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Role | EnumRoleFilter | undefined'.ts(2322)
(property) role?: Role | Prisma.EnumRoleFilter | undefined
```

Code that caused the error:

```
const dummyOwnerUser = {
    ...
    role: "OWNER"
}
let ownerUser = await client.user.findFirst({
    where: {
        ...
        role: dummyOwnerUser.role
    }
})
```

No error:

```
const dummyOwnerUser = {
    ...
    role: "OWNER" as RoleType
}
let ownerUser = await client.user.findFirst({
    where: {
        ...
        role: dummyOwnerUser.role
    }
})
```

So presumably OP needed to cast `status` as a `TodoStatusType` prior to making the query.

**Edit:**

It's probably quite important to mention I'm using `zod-prisma-types` from npm!

Answer (score 0):

[David answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71593761/11699556) works, But it is better to validate req.query using ClassValidator or Zod and set the type inside the validator as TodoStatus instead of normal string.